# How to select a checkbox and auto select other related checkbox.?

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

I have the following code. My goal is to select a checkbox then all otehr related checkbox will be selected as well.  I am able to do auto select other checkbox when I select the first checkbox and the next group checkbox, but it is not working when I select the second checkbox and first checkbox is related to second one, the first checkbox not selected automatically,

Looks like the loop is not going back to forth. Where went wrong with my code?

```
DECLARE
    v_selected_contract       VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_selected_contract_ver   NUMBER;
    v_selected_contract_n     VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_selected_contract_ver_n NUMBER;
BEGIN
    Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');

    --  first_record;
    IF :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected = 'Y' THEN
      v_selected_contract := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num;
      v_selected_contract_ver := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num;

      WHILE :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num = v_selected_contract
            AND :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num =
                v_selected_contract_ver
      LOOP
          :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected := 'Y';
          EXIT WHEN :System.last_record = 'TRUE';
          next_record;
      END LOOP;
      Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');
      first_record;
    ELSE
      v_selected_contract_n := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num;
      v_selected_contract_ver_n := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num;

      WHILE :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num = v_selected_contract_n
            AND :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num =
                v_selected_contract_ver_n LOOP
          :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected := 'N';
          EXIT WHEN :System.last_record = 'TRUE';
          next_record;
      END LOOP;

      Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');

      first_record;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
  Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');
  first_record;
```

should be there before you start the loop, else if you click on the second record, the records after the second one will get selected, loop exits, and the control goes to the first record, but you don't select it.

This is how it should be:

```
DECLARE
    v_selected_contract       VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_selected_contract_ver   NUMBER;
    v_selected_contract_n     VARCHAR2 (50);
    v_selected_contract_ver_n NUMBER;
BEGIN

    IF :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected = 'Y' THEN -- first current record is checked
       Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');   -- go to the block 
       first_record;  -- first record, then loop and select all.
      v_selected_contract := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num;
      v_selected_contract_ver := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num;

      WHILE :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num = v_selected_contract
            AND :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num =
                v_selected_contract_ver
      LOOP
          :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected := 'Y';
          EXIT WHEN :System.last_record = 'TRUE';
          next_record;
      END LOOP;
      Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');
      first_record;
    ELSE
      Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');   -- go to the block 
      first_record;  -- first record, then loop and unselect all.
      v_selected_contract_n := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num;
      v_selected_contract_ver_n := :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num;

      WHILE :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_num = v_selected_contract_n
            AND :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.contract_version_num =
                v_selected_contract_ver_n LOOP
          :PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES.selected := 'N';
          EXIT WHEN :System.last_record = 'TRUE';
          next_record;
      END LOOP;

      Go_block('PCMS_CONTRACT_LINES');

      first_record;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: do you mean i  uncomment the  --first_record? thanks.

Comment: hi after i uncommented that line,  i am able to select the first check box and auto checked the second, but if i check second first, both of the checkbox cant be checked  remaining unchecked

Comment: see my edit, first_record should be there there under the if & else parts